# Docker-machine Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

I am using Docker on mac os x 10.10.5 I am having all sorts of issues with permissions primarily. I was able to create `sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox test` then the result of `sudo docker-machine env test`

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.102:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/michaelaubry/.docker/machine/machines/test"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="test"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $(docker-machine env test)
```

Then I run `eval $(docker-machine env test)` and the result is `open /Users/michaelaubry/.docker/machine/machines/test/config.json: permission denied`

I run `sudo chown michaelaubry:staff /Users/michaelaubry/.docker/machine/machines/test/config.json` and still `open /Users/michaelaubry/.docker/machine/machines/test/config.json: permission denied`

Then I try this

```
~ » sudo chown michaelaubry:staff /Users/michaelaubry/.docker/machine/machines/test/
~ » sudo chown michaelaubry:staff /Users/michaelaubry/.docker/machine/machines/
~ » sudo chown michaelaubry:staff /Users/michaelaubry/.docker/machine/
~ » sudo chown michaelaubry:staff /Users/michaelaubry/.docker/
~ » eval $(docker-machine env test)
Error checking TLS connection: machine does not exist
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you should have created the machine using `sudo`? That seems to have caused permssion problems. Just `docker-machine create...` without sudo works well for me.

Comment: I ran without sudo I get this `Error with pre-create check: "VirtualBox is configured with multiple host-only adapters with the same IP \"192.168.99.1\". Please remove one."` Let me try and wipe everything

Comment: Sounds like virtualbox is already running as root then. Maybe do a `sudo docker-machine stop test` before attempting to start it as yourself.

Comment: So clean install `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox test` gives me the same `Error with pre-create check: "VirtualBox is configured with multiple host-only adapters with the same IP \"192.168.99.1\". Please remove one."` so ok I do this `sudo docker-machine stop default` then `docker-machine start` now back to permissions issue with config.json `open /Users/michaelaubry/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json: permission denied` Let me see if ownership is changed.

Comment: Ok I gave ownership to myself for the `config.json` then I run `docker-machine start` result is `Starting "default"...` then `machine does not exist`... ok fine so I run `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default` then `Host already exists: "default"`

Comment: If you start the virtualbox gui, are there machines showing up that could be related to docker?

Comment: Crap, good call on checking virtualbox, my box was called `Default` with capitol `D` oh my gosh